# Formatting a string with NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I have this app of mine where one text field must behave like a calculator display would. The number this text field shows is calculated by a function. If the number is, for example, "3.21" it should be displayed like this, with 2 decimal places. If the number has more decimal places, it should be displayed with the number of decimal places it has.

The textfield allows displaying 10 digits.

If the number is bigger than 9999999999 (10 nines) it should be displayed in scientific notation, like "4.767 E20" or something like that.

I suppose I have to use `NSNumberFormatter` for that matter but I see that I will have a series of ifs and a complicate sequence of `NSNumberFormatter`s to do the job, specially for the number of decimal places.

My question is: is this the way to go or is there some kind of `NSNumberFormatter` that can do this automatically?

Comment: Did you check it with `NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a number formatter at all. You can use the %g format string, from either Swift or Objective-C. The Swift code would look like this:

```
import UIKit
var value = 0.0
for digits in 1...12 {
  value = value * 10 + 9
  print(String(format:"%.10g", value))
}
```

That yields the result:

```
9
99
999
9999
99999
999999
9999999
99999999
999999999
9999999999
1e+11
1e+12
```

In Objective-C, you'd use `NSString`'s `stringWithFormat` method, and also use the format string @"%.10g"

My Objective-C is getting rusty, but the code would look something like this:

```
double value = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
  value = value * 10 + 9;
  NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.10g", value];
  NSLog(@"value = %@", result);
}
```

Comment: this is almost working well but when I add a number with 11 digits it produces "inf". In my case, my variable is long double and Xcode forced me to use `%.10Lg`

Comment: Are you running on a 32 bit device? When I run that code in a playground (Which runs in x86 64) I can display Double values with almost any number of digits in scientific notation. Changing the loop to go up to 15, or even 25, works just fine. I haven't tried running the code on an iOS device, but it should work just fine there as well (at least for 64 bit devices)

Comment: Oh, you're using Objective-C? (long double isn't a valid type in Swift.)